# How can I show desktop view on mobile browser devices?

Tags: html, mobile, browser, desktop

I'm trying to show desktop view on mobile devices because optimizing it could be a problem. I already tried with:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
```

Here's my code: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bw5vomfs/5/)

Hope someone can help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remove the meta tag and it works.
Pay attention to Safari's responsive design mode, it does not fit, probably by cache.